# AJAX cart in popup (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I developing my own WooCommerce theme. I want to realize cart in popup in which all changes will show without reloading.
I already make adding to cart without reloading, but I don't know how to realize my idea about remove items. Now when I remove some item the page is reloading, but I want to remove items and save changes without page refresh.
Tell me, please, how to do it?

**My php-code:**
(function popup_cart_template() is default code from cart.php customized for my template)

```
//ajax adding items
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'cart_popup_fragment', 30, 1 );
function cart_popup_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    ob_start();
    popup_cart_template();
    $fragments['.cart__table'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;

}

//cart template function
function popup_cart_template() {
    wc_get_template( 'cart/cart-popup.php' ); 
}

//cart-popup.php content
    
<table class="cart__table" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="cart__header_quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'QTY', 'woocommerce' ); ?></td>
                    <td class="cart__header_cost"><?php esc_html_e( 'Cost', 'woocommerce' ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="cart__items">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

                <?php
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                    $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                        $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                        <tr class="cart__item woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                            <td class="cart__item_image product-thumbnail">
                                <?php
                                    echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                                        sprintf('<a href="%s" class="cart__item-remove remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">
                                            X
                                            </a>',
                                            esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                            esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                            esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                        ),
                                        $cart_item_key
                                    );

<!-- and other code...:) -->
```

**My html-code:**

```
<section class="cart__layout popup" id="cart">
        <div class="cart__body">
            <div class="cart__content popup__content">

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

                <div class="popup-close close-popup">
                    <img src="assets/img/popup/close-icon.png" alt="close-icon" class="popup-close__icon">
                </div>
                <h1 class="cart__title">
                    CART
                </h1>
                <?php popup_cart_template(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Looks like you're designing a mini cart with your own HTML and CSS classes. Since you're not using the classes that WooCommerce usages in JS code so Ajax request is not being triggered on the remove button click and your page is being reloaded. You can either rewrite JS code with your new CSS classes or you can try to customize the mini cart with the default WooCommerce classes so that JS functions don't get affected.

Comment: Yeah, you're right!